# Left Aligned Equations with Align Stops in LaTeX

Tags: latex

I am trying to get a group of simple equations that will be left aligned as much as they can but also respect alignment `&` marks. I am using MiKTeX on Windows 8.1.

With a single stop, this works fine:

```
\begin{align*}
a+b+c^2_5=&d\\
e^5+f_{44}+g=&h
\end{align*}
```

[image]

But as soon as I add in additional `&`, all hell breaks loose:

```
\begin{align*}
a+b+&c^2_5=&d\\
e^5+f_{44}+&g=&h
\end{align*}
```

[image]

Basically, I'd like for a way to align certain variables with each other, then mush it left as far as possible. I am probably describing that poorly. :(

I have tried `flalign` and have similar results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the `alignat` environment, it doesn't add extra spacing
between the columns.

In the following example, one column is aligned at the second `+` sign,
the other column is aligned at the `=` sign.

```latex
%                +--- number of columns
%                |
\begin{alignat*}{2}
           a + b &+ c^2_5 &= d\\
    e^5 + f_{44} &+ g     &= h
\end{alignat*}
```

[image]

Comment: @sergej Thank you, this works out perfectly. `\begin{alignat*}{2}
&x_4&=-2\\\\
&x_3-4x_4&=8\\
\Rightarrow& x_3-4(-2)&=8\\
\Rightarrow& x_3+8&=8\\
\Rightarrow& x_3&=0\\\\
&x_2+x_3+x_4&=2\\
\Rightarrow& x_2+0-2&=2\\
\Rightarrow& x_2&=4\\\\
&x_1+x_2+x_3&=5\\
\Rightarrow& x_1+4+0&=5\\
\Rightarrow& x_1&=1\\
\end{alignat*}` http://i.imgur.com/CBC4vie.png

Comment: @BaconCatBug You are welcome, looks nice ;)